# Codeigniter reuseable layout?

Tags: function, codeigniter, layout

In my controller I have to copy and paste this 4 lines of code everytime I make a function in controller.

```
 $this->load->view('include/header', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/nav', $data);
 $this->load->view('page/index', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer');
```

Is there a way to avoid this copy and paste. Like create a function and call it. Please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly it is "master layout codeigniter"

Please view link above:

[How to create Master Page(Layout) with base design style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976737/how-to-create-master-pagelayout-with-base-design-style)

Package for you: https://github.com/scotch-io/stencil

I hope help you!