# How to load same content over all page?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Instead of calling same data inside each functions in controllers i want to load that data globally by calling once.
i did

```
MY_Controller.php
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','file'));
         $this->load->model('common/common_model');
         $data['header_menus'] = $this->common_model->categoryMenus();
     }
}
```

This file is inside core folder and in controller folder there is a controller and i did

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {
```

while loading function inside home controller how do i load $data['header_menus'] in views do i need to do saomething with that variable in function again?

Comment: you  not use layout? Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976737/how-to-create-master-pagelayout-with-base-design-style

Comment: put all this in 'view helper' & call this helper from layout

Answer (score 1):

**Create one view in View folder and load that view in controller, make changes in your controller:**

**For example, your view name is display_view.php in view folder:**

**MY_Controller.php**

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','file'));
         $this->load->model('common/common_model');
         $data['header_menus'] = $this->common_model->categoryMenus();
         $this->load->view('tour/view',$data);
     }
}
```

**display_view.php**

```
<?php
if(!empty($header_menus)) {
  extract($header_menus);
}
print_r($header_menus); // you can get all the info here
?>
```

[Load View in Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check about inheritance.

```
$data['header_menus'] = $this->common_model->categoryMenus();
```

has to be

```
$this->data['header_menus'] = $this->common_model->categoryMenus();
```

In extending controller you need to call it with

```
$this->data['header_menus'];
```

Use `$this->data` array for other variables too and call the view with something like:

```
$this->load->view('some_view_file', $this->data);
```

Read in docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php), [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php).